# Jenkins htmlpublisher generating phpdox as empty page

Tags: html, jenkins, ant, continuous-integration, html-parsing

Trying to implement HTMLpublisher in order to archieve generated PHPDox in my Jenkins CI process, I am getting an empty output that gets archieved:

[image: Output htmlpublisher]

Within my Post Actions, I've configured the following:
[image: htmlpublisher config]

while the directory build/api/html contains the generated phpdox files:

[image]

When I open the index.xhtml file, I can access the generated phpdox page, but trying to open the "htmlpublished" phpdox, I get the image shown above. What did I do wrong?

---

**A satisfying answer will be rewarded with 50 reputation points.**